# How to separate a realisation of template constructor (if the class isn't template)

Tags: c++, templates

I've read this page [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)
but it's about a template class. And the constructor takes same type as class (if class is < int >, constructor also takes int, and so on). But I have simple (non-template) class. Sorry for duplication, please explain what should I do in this case?

I have a class 'Object' with field 'double d' and I want to make a template constructor. If I realize it inside the class, all works good, but if move the realisation outside of the class (from .h to .cpp), it doesn't work. Here's my code:

Object.h

```
class Object {
    double d;
public:
    template <class T> Object(T t);
};
```

Object.cpp

```
#include "Object.h"

template <class T> Object::Object(T t) {
    d = t;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Object.h"

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    Object x(a);
    float b = 2.5;
    Object y(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Error appears in main.cpp in lines that creates x and y, there are:

```
undefined reference to `Object::Object<int>(int)'
undefined reference to `Object::Object<float>(float)'
```

Comment: 100% duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `Object.cpp` and move its contents to a header file.

When the compiler deals with `Object.cpp`, it doesn't generate any byte code because there are only some templates. When it encounters a 'mention' of `Object::Object<int>(int)` in your code, it goes to the header file, deduces the template parameters and successfully compiles everything.

The linker, however, isn't happy. It sees a call to `Object::Object<int>(int)`, but can't find byte code for this method and raises an error.

Otherwise, you can define `template <class T> Object::Object(T t)` in `main`, but that's not so good and may lead to confusion.

Comment: About adding  
"template class Object<int>;  
template class Object<float>; "
at the beginning of main.cpp - it doesn't work because I have non-template class (not "template <class T> Object", but simple "class Object").

Comment: So it's remaining one question - is it a good tone to write the realisation of constructor inside the interface?

Comment: @Pavel, if this constructor isn't very long, then it's OK

Comment: If I understand right, interface needs to show user which methods he can use

Comment: @Pavel, that's why they're called _interfaces_

Answer (score 0):

You must implement *all* templates you want to use in the header file. If you only implement them in the .cpp file, only that .cpp file can see it.